# ajax get data from a rails controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I am trying to use ajax to get information from my controller. Basically I want to know if a data already exists in the DB or not, so my controller will return either true or false.
At the moment I am just trying to set the basic ajax call

in my js file I have the following ajax call, as you can see at the moment I am not really doing any logic because my data is just a placeholder. Later I will add the information I want to query

```
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "/locations/exists",
  dataType: "JSON",
  data: { 'locition_exist': loc_exit },
  success: function(data) {
    console.log(data);
  }
});
```

In my controller I have

```
  def exists
    location_exists = true
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.json {render json: location_exists }
    end
  end
```

Later value will go into a method in the model that will query the DB and return true/false.

In my routes I have

```
  resources :locations 
  get 'locations/exists', to: 'locations#exists'
```

This code results in the following error

```
The action 'show' could not be found for LocationsController
```

I am new to rails and ajax , and I based my code on different examples that I read here, so I am probably just doing a stupid noob mistake.
Thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When using `get` or `match` in routes, you need to define the controller method mapped

```
get 'locations/value', to: 'locations#value'
```

**update**

You saw the same error after updating routes. There are two reasons of this error:

1. You defined `resources :location` at first. The url `locations/exists` itself matches "show" method within resources, with Routes taking `'exists'` as the id in `#show`.
2. You have not defined `show` within LocationsController

So, Routes will firstly map the url to `locations#show` with the `:id` as `'exists'`, then hits the controller and found `#show` does not exist.

**The solution after your updating**

Of course you can put `get 'exists'...` before resources but that looks ugly.

Since `'exists'` requires no id, it is a collection method. So you can use Routes built-in ways to do that.

```
resources :locations do
  collection do
    get 'exists'
  end
end
```

By this all your resources and 'exists' can live.

Comment: I've updated my code in my post. This still results in the same error.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. I will read more about collection to better understand your suggestion :)

Comment: @Quantico, my pleasure :) You can read the doc here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#non-resourceful-routes